# DSN: Data format error

Tags: php, ubuntu, sendmail

пытаюсь отправить сообщения с сервера Ubuntu nginx через sendmail выдает вот такую ошибку

```
Aug 14 09:24:53 test sendmail[22190]: v7E9OrwY022190: to=nsd@gmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30133, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (v7E9OrUd022191 Message accepted for delivery)
Aug 14 09:24:53 test sm-mta[22193]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Aug 14 09:24:53 test sm-mta[22193]: v7E9OrUd022191: to=<nsd@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@test.wt> (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120375, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [64.233.166.27], dsn=5.6.0, stat=Data format error
Aug 14 09:24:53 test sm-mta[22193]: v7E9OrUd022191: v7E9OrUd022193: DSN: Data format error
```

когда пытаюсь отправить через php код

```
<?php
mail ("nsd@gmail.com","sdfsdfs",
             "xdgsdgs","nsd@gmail.com");
?>
```

но если отправлять напрямую с сервера через

```
root@test:~# telnet 127.0.0.1 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 test.wt ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-3; Mon, 14 Aug 2017 09:41:50 GMT; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost.localdomain(OK)-localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]

helo server
250 test.wt Hello localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
MAIL from:nsd@gmail.com
250 2.1.0 nsd@gmail.com... Sender ok
RCPT to:nsd@gmail.com
250 2.1.5 nsd@gmail.com... Recipient ok
DATA
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
Subject: ndfgjkd
from:nsd@gmail.com
to:nsd@gmail.com
Test Mail
.
250 2.0.0 v7E9fo40022316 Message accepted for delivery
```

все работает прекрасно и отправляется.
Вопрос: Почему напрямую отправляется а через php код выдает ошибку

hostname = test.wt
hosts =

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1 test.wt

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

проблема скорее всего вот тут

```
Return-Path: <www-data@test.wt>
Received: from test.wt (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by test.wt (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-3) with ESMTP id v7EEjxi2028126
    for <nsd@gmail.com>; Mon, 14 Aug 2017 14:45:59 GMT
Received: (from www-data@localhost)
    by test.wt (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) id v7EEjx79028125;
    Mon, 14 Aug 2017 14:45:59 GMT
Date: Mon, 14 Aug 2017 14:45:59 GMT
From: www-data <www-data@test.wt>
Message-Id: <201708141445.v7EEjx79028125@test.wt>
To: nsd@gmail.com
Subject: dfdgsf
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:send.php

--v7EEjxi2028128.1502721959/test.wt--
```

вопрос как поменять вот эти строчки  `Return-Path: <www-data@test.wt>`, `From: www-data <www-data@test.wt>`

Comment: вероятно, что-то наконфигурировали вы неправильное у программы sendmail. попробуйте «вернуть всё назад». а ещё лучше, вероятно, поставить smtp с «более человеческим лицом» — «родной» для debian-а и наследников exim или, на худой конец, postfix.

Comment: @alexander barakin я совсем недавно начал всем этим пользоваться можно как нибудь поподробней

Comment: @alexander barakin например с тем как вернуть все назад в sendmail

Comment: вы не помните, какие изменения вносили в конфигурацию прогаммы? тогда проще удалить пакет вместе с конфигурацией (`apt-get purge ...`) и снова установить.

Comment: @alexander barakin непомогло, а можете по подробней рассказать о smtp

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

удалил sendmail() поставил postfix все работает